# Trying to connect to ethernet devices from remote computer

Tags: networking, vpn, ping, remote-debugging, plc

I'm looking to establish a connection between my laptop and a remote PC in such a way that I can ping other devices connected to one of its network cards from my laptop.

That might be a little unclear- let me be more specific:
I am a PLC programmer, and my company just migrated to a brand of PLC that requires individual software licenses for each "station."  So we're not going to be spending the money for the programming software at each location- instead, each technician will have a laptop, and he can physically visit whichever location needs troubleshooting.

However, that gets to be a lot of travel (international, in some cases), and I'm looking to come up with a way (using a VPN or something) so that I can connect to a PLC remotely.

Our setup is a Windows 7 Industrial PC at the customer's location with two network cards- one is hooked up to the customer's network (and the internet), and the other is hooked into the various PLCs, all with static IPs in the same range.  I'm trying to minimize the amount of software I'll have to install/purchase for this project- we already use Teamviewer, but its VPN connection doesn't seem capable of accomplishing what I want (at least, I've never been able to manage a successful ping to one of the PLCs, no matter how much I mess with settings, and their support consists mainly of "buy our newest version").

I've seen lots of posts about this kind of stuff on the internet, but a lot of it seems directed to people who either already know how to set this stuff up and just want to know which software is cheapest, or it is specific to the brand of PLC (I'm using Lenze, which is not very common in english-speaking countries, or at least in america).

Anybody who has managed something like this- I'd really appreciate some sort of walkthrough, or at the very least some pointers in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

VPN is for TPC/IP communication. Whenever you need layer 2 from ethernet, you're stuck. I know that Step 7 TIA from Siemens can not find for PLCs via VPN. Explaination from support is that searching goes via layer 2. And this list can be made longer.

Most brands can now handle programming via memory cards. Just program local, write it to a memory card and plug it into your PLC.

Just contact the companies and see what they have to offer. The times are still here that PLC brands are fighting for customers. Let them do the work for you and enjoy. It works for our company. :)